# prevent iPad popover arrow from moving when I resize the popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm using a navigation controller inside a popover controller. The various pages in the navigation controller have different sizes. When I move through the pages in the navigation controller, the popover resizes accordingly. The arrow also shifts position. How can I prevent the arrow from moving?